# Windows - why won't Win32com application run in .py or .pyw mode?

Tags: python, win32com

I have written a language learning application that I would like to be able to run in .pyw mode. But, apparently because I am using Win32com (for Sapi voices) it will only run from my editor (Idle). This is related to an earlier post, where I thought I was running into a conflict between tkinter and pyttsx3. But now, using neither pyttsx3 or tkinter, I am running into the same problem.

To be very clear about this - here is a simple piece of code:

```
userinput = input("Press any key")
```

Not surprisingly, this code runs fine from my editor (in the shell), and also runs fine simply by double clicking the .py file (runs in the console). And it will also run fine if I rename to a .pyw file and double click.

Here is another simple piece of code using Sapi text to speech:

```
import win32com.client
speaker = win32com.client.Dispatch ("SAPI.SpVoice")
speaker.Speak ("Hello World")
```

This code runs fine from Idle (my editor)
But it will not run by clicking the .py file or a .pyw file. I get a very quick flash of the console, and it shuts down without speaking.

Just to test, I added a user input line like this:

```
import win32com.client
speaker = win32com.client.Dispatch ("SAPI.SpVoice")
speaker.Speak ("Hello World")
userinput = input("Press any key")
```

My thinking was that, in order to force the application to persist, I would enter a user prompt. But that did not work. I ended up with the same brief flash of the console, and nothing happened. It did not speak, nor did it wait for user input.

This matters because, in my experience, if the application will not run in .pyw mode, it will also not run after using pyinstaller. You will simply get the same brief flash of the console and...nothing.

With apologies, I am new to programming, and new to Python. What am I missing here? How can I make the application run from .pyw mode?

Comment: Open the console and run the program with `python ` + filename of script (in the right directory) to see a possible error message. You may have to specify the path to your `python.exe` depending on your configuration.

Comment: Many thanks. That may well be the problem. However, I went to my C: drive and searched for python.exe and it came up with at least 20 instances (including many python.exe, some pythonw.exe, some python-3.4.7.exe and so on. Is there some way to determine which specific .exe file Idle is pointing to?

Comment: You must then find out where the idle.exe or script is located. This is usually a subdirectory of the Python installation which contains the appropriate python.exe.